# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Jquery UI drag and drop function for moving div from 1 tr to another with in a table but when I drop I get the issue.

Below is my function:

```
 $(".appdrop").droppable({
                accept: ".appdrag",
                activeClass: 'droppable-active',
                hoverClass: 'droppable-hover',
                drop: function (ev, ui) {
                    // alert(ui.draggable.attr('id'));
                    // alert($(this).attr('id'));
                    var a = $(this).attr('id');
                    var arr = a.split(',');
                    CutAppointmentId=ui.draggable.attr('id');
                    slotid = arr[0].replace('Slotid', '');
                    slotdetailid = arr[1].replace('TimeSlotDtlId', '');            
                    params["TimeSlotDtlId"] = slotdetailid;
                    params["CutAppointmentId"] = CutAppointmentId;

                    Scheduling_Calendar.MoveAppointment(CutAppointmentId, slotdetailid).done(function (response) {
                        if (response.status != false) {
                            utility.DisplayMessages(response.Message, 1);
                            ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
                        }
                        else {
                            utility.DisplayMessages(response.Message, 3);
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

Below mentioned line create document fragment issue when I used in my function Scheduling_Calendar.MoveAppointment() :

```
ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
```

and if i am not use Scheduling_Calendar.MoveAppointment() function it will execute without any issue.
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.